# Update based on Find at another table

Tags: c#, linq

As Find can't be used that way what is the best way to do something like that with pure LINQ?

```cs
dbContext.Exports
  .Where(x => x.ExportDate < DateTime.UtcNow.Add((dbContext.Configurations.Find(x.ConfigurationId).Timeout) 
    && x.anotherCondition == "xyz")
  .Update(x => new Export() { Status = "Failed" });
```

between table Configurations and Exports, there is no relation on EF data model.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: LINQ is a query language.  You cannot update via LINQ so you use it to get your objects and then iterate over them to perform the update itself.  You could wrap this process in an extension class so that you can still achieve what you want in a single line.

Comment: See [EF Core Tools & Extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/extensions/) - some libraries can help. Pay attention to linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore. This extension will most likely help to make the update a single request. See [docs](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db#update)

Comment: @Ermiya-Eskandary I try to use a value from dbContext.Configurations.Find(x.ConfigurationId).Timeout (so something like subquery) to update dbContext.Exports. Of course, the problem is with that semi subquery, as that is not allowed.

Comment: @alexander-petrov problem is not with an update but with subquery to get timeout

Comment: Which extension do you use? Such `Update` is not supported by vanilla EF Core.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I use Entity Framework Plus. Still, my problem does is not "update", the problem is with the subquery

Comment: `Entity Framework Plus` will not create correct query in this case. Only `linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore` can do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a foreign key here:

```
[Table("Exports")]
public partial class Exports
{
      public long configurationId { get; set; }

      [ForeignKey("configurationId")]
      public virtual Configuration Configuration { get; set; }
}
```

Then your query will look like this:

```
dbContext.Exports
  .Where(x => x.ExportDate < DateTime.UtcNow.Add(x.Configuration.Timeout)) 
  .Where(x => x.anotherCondition == "xyz")
  .Update(x => new Export() { Status = "Failed" });
```